# Session: Configured save path 'C:\Windows\Temp' is not writable by the PHP process

Tags: codeigniter

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Exception
>
> Message: Session: Configured save path 'C:\Windows\Temp' is not
>   writable by the PHP process.
>
> Filename:
>   prm\system\libraries\Session\drivers\Session_files_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 125
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: \prm\application\controllers\login.php Line: 8 Function:
>   __construct
>
> File: \prm\index.php Line: 279 Function: require_once

Not able to fix this issue. please suggest how to fix this

Comment: add your code as well

Comment: C:\Windows\Temp, give permission for writable... i mean in Windows unmark it from Read Only from folder property.

Answer (score 15):

We are setting up 'C:\Windows\Temp' windows directory path to database ci_session table.

change the following in your config file.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

to

```
$config['sess_driver']= 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name']= 'mycookie';
$config['sess_expiration']= 0;
$config['sess_save_path']= 'ci_session';
$config['sess_match_ip']= FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']= 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy']= FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']= TRUE;
$config['sess_expire_on_close']= TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']= 'ci_session';
```

Comment: I faced this issue in Windows server using Codeigniter Framework..The above solution Fixed it.

Comment: This solution helped me as well

Comment: didn't he said he want to convert to database ?

Comment: I got three  errors
1) ci_session   doesn't exist
2) Message: session_write_close(): Cannot call session save handler in a recursive manner
3) Message: session_write_close(): Failed to write session data using user defined save handler. (session.save_path: /opt/lampp/temp/)

Comment: what are the columns in ci_session table?

Answer (score 10):

Edit config.php

Location: application/config/config.php

Before

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

After

```
$sessDir = session_save_path();
$sessDir = "{$sessDir}/sessionPath";
is_dir($sessDir)?:mkdir($sessDir);

$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = $sessDir;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

It's work for me

Comment: @Sanjay Khatri it's my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

In your application's config.php file search for $config['sess_save_path'] change its default value of sys_get_temp_dir() to another publicly accessible directory preferably not in the C: drive.

or you can set it globally in your php.ini file and call ini_get ('session.save_path'), but first make sure you have changed the default value of that option to a temp directory of your choice.

Comment: It was $config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'cache/'; i changed to sys_get_temp_dir(); and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

This error basically tells you that the PHP process does not have the permission to write to the cache directory specified in your config.

The simplest, clearest solution would be to grant write permission for the directory.

I don't use a windows machine so I can't tell you exactly how to do it, but you can look that up.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after I created a new CodeIgniter 4 project with Composer.

Normally sessions are saved in the folder specified in php.ini with setting session.save_path. You can check this by calling

```
phpinfo();
```

and look for

```
session.save_path
```

I was surprised to find out that the CodeIgniter tries to save the data in a different folder. It is configured in file app/Config/Paths.php. The variable to look for is

```
$writableDirectory
```

The (default) line of code is

```
public string $writableDirectory = __DIR__ . '/../../writable
```

I tried to remove the readonly flag from the folder, but that didn't work. Some process or application kept me from removing it. (I suspected Google Drive). Note: I am on Windows, but that doesn't really matter... I think.

Creating a new folder named "writable2" next to it and changing the setting to

```
public string $writableDirectory = __DIR__ . '/../../writable2
```

solved the problem.

Still don't know which process or application changed (and kept on changing) the folder to readonly. Changing the name back from writable2 to writable and the problem is back.
Deleting folder writable and renaming folder writable2 to writable works though. Weird!